# How to get fpointer to point to an html file in the network?

Tags: c, fgets

I'm basically trying to get to print a string from the login page of my router (well, the HTML file) but i don't know how to get c to point to a url.

I started with this, which obviously wasn't going to work but I'm new to this and I had to try.

```
#include <stdio.h>

    char line [255];

int main()
{
    FILE * fpointer = fopen("http://192.168.0.1/login.html", "r");

    fgets(line, 255, fpointer);
    printf("%s", line);

    fclose(fpointer);
    return 0;
}
```

I have almost no idea of programming, i just want to know how can I do what this program should be able to do with any file in my computer, but with a url.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to take a *long* time to get familiar with C first, before you try to to do *network programming*. And note that the `f` in `fopen` is for *File*, and files are local only.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Should work with NFS/Samba shares, no?

Comment: @EugeneSh. True, but from the applications point of view (and the point of view of `fopen`) those are really local files as they are paths to local mount-points (for NFS) or mounted as a local drive (SMB/Windows).

Comment: There's no simple way to do what you appear to be trying to do. The [fopen()](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html) function is for opening files on your local disk (or files that _appear to be_ on your local disk if you have network-mounted filesystems). Using the HTTP protocol to access content in someone's web server is a completely different beast.  Perhaps you want to look into using something like [libcurll](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)?

Answer (score 1):

You may use `popen` function with `curl` command.

```c
FILE *fp = popen("curl http://192.168.0.1/login.html", "r");
if (fp == NULL) {
  // Error. throw Exception or report  
}

char buffer[MAX_SIZE];
while (fgets(buffer, MAX_SIZE, fp) != NULL) {
    processChunk(buffer);
}

pclose(fp);
```